# NoActivityResumedException when testing activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-espresso

I have one activity with on button and, inside this activity, I added a fragment where user can choose videos, and then, click on the button on activity, and goes to another activity.
I'm testing with espresso, and when I select videos and try to click on button, I see this

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
```

here is my test

```
 public void testVideosSelectToMix(){
    selectVideoAt(0);
    selectVideoAt(1);

    // Fails at this line: the commit button on activity
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.commit))).perform(click());
    onView(withText(R.string.title_video_merge_fragment)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

I think that this may be related to the listener on commit button, that calls `finish();` but why does it work on emulator/device and not on my tests?

Comment: can you confirm again that the test breaks on the line the commit button is clicked? If is the last one, it may make more sense. Are you running your tests with animation turned off? Do you use in this process an AsyncTask for something?

Comment: Hey @Lxu I fixed this some days ago...can't remeber exactly what I did, but solved...I think I updagred to JUnit 4, but thanks anyway!